Inequality involving exponentials and factorials
Let $b>1$ (a base), $n\ge 2$ and $1\le k\le n$. I would like to know for which $k$ the inequalities
$$
\frac{1}{n!}b^{n-1}\le \frac{b^k-1}{(n-k)!}\le\frac{1}{(n-1)!}(b^n-1)(b-1).
$$
hold or at least obtain some good asymptotics.
Note that the expression in the middle is monotonically increasing in $k$. Numerical calculations suggest that for e.g. $b=10$ there are always at most two values of $k$ satisfying the inequalities.
I have tried a lot of things. When focussing on the right inequality first and taking $\log_b$ we have
$$
\log_b\left(\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!}\right)+\log_b(b^k-1)-\log(b-1)\le\log_b(b^n-1)
$$
for which it is sufficient to check if
$$
\log_b\left(\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!}\right)+k\le n-1.
$$
Using that $\tfrac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!}=(n-1)...(n-(k-1))\le (n-1)^{k-1}$ it is also sufficient to check if
$$
(k-1)\log_b((n-1))\le n-k-1 \Leftrightarrow k\le \frac{n-1+\log_b(n-1)}{1+\log_b(n-1)}.
$$

In this image the horizontal axis contains values of $n$ and the quantity $\log_{10}\left(\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)!}\right)$ is mapped in blue for one of the possible values of $k$ for which the above inequalities hold. In orange we have $\log_{10}\left(\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k^\prime)!}\right)$, where $k^\prime=\frac{n-1+\log_b(n-1)}{1+\log_b(n-1)}$. This approximation does not seem to be asymptotic and it also undershoots the quantity and therefore leaves out possible values of $k$.
For the other inequality a similar argument does not work so well. We want
$$
n-1\le \log_b\left(\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\right)+\log_b(b^k-1)
$$
for which it is sufficient to have
$$
n-k \le \log_b\left(\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\right).
$$
As $\tfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}=n(n-1)...(n-(k-1))\ge (n-k+1)^k$ it is also sufficient to check
$$
n-k\le k\log_b(n-k+1)
$$
but I can't simplify this expression further.
Does anyone have another approach to bound the possible values of $k$ nicely? If is helps, you may assume that $b=2$ for now.

Reading your post it seems that you have indeed two questions:
a) When does the left (resp. the right) inequality hold?
b) For which $(b, k, n )$  do both inequalities hold simultaneously?
The answer to a) will shine light on b), so I can  offer something for a) and at least a discussion for b).
What I will demonstrate is an investigation of the range of $k$, with  the result:
for $k=1$, the left inequality is (almost) always violated and the right inequality always holds.
for $k=n$, the left inequality  (almost) always holds and the right inequality is (almost) always violated.
Let $k=1$. Then the left inequality reads $b^{n-1} < n (b-1)$. For $n=2$, this is true only for $b>2$.  For $n\ge 3$, it is always wrong. Write $b = 1+q$ with $q >0$, then we will show the opposite of the desired statement, i.e. it suffices to show
$$
(1+q)^{n-1} > n q\\
1 + q(n-1) + \frac 12 q^2 (n-1)(n-2) > nq\\
1 - q +  \frac12 q^2 (n-1)(n-2) > 0\\
q^2 - 2 q \frac{1}{(n-1)(n-2)} + \frac{1}{(n-1)^2(n-2)^2 }+ \frac{2 (n-1)(n-2)-1}{(n-1)^2(n-2)^2} > 0 \\
(q-  \frac{1}{(n-1)(n-2)} )^2+ \frac{2 (n-1)(n-2)-1}{(n-1)^2(n-2)^2} > 0\\
2 (n-1)(n-2)-1 > 0
$$
and the last statement is true for $n\ge 3$.
The right inequality reads for $k=1$: $(b-1) < (b^n - 1)(b-1)$ which is always true.
Now let $k=n$. The left inequality reads $\frac{1}{n!}b^{n-1}\le b^n-1$ or $\frac{1}{n!}\le b-\frac{1}{b^{n-1}}$ . Now in the last formulation, the LHS is falling with $n$ whereas the RHS is rising with $n$. Hence it is enough to show for some $b$ that it is true, which sets this $b$ to $0  = b^n - \frac{1}{n!}b^{n-1}-1$. This gives falling $b$ with $n$, the values are $(n,b) = (2,1.28) ; (3,1.06) ; (4,1.01) \cdots$ with a limit of $(n,1)$. So if we are happy with $b > 1.28$, we have that the left inequality is true.
The right inequality reads $b^n-1\le\frac{1}{(n-1)!}(b^n-1)(b-1)$ or $(n-1)! + 1\le\ b $. This is only true for large $b$ as $n$ increases, so let $n \ge 3$ and $b \le 3$ and it is violated. (If larger $n$ are considered, this statement holds for much larger $b$.)
This leads us to question b) For which $(b, k, n )$  do both inequalities hold simultaneously?
Excluding the special cases above leads to the case of $n \ge 3$ and $1.28<b<3$ where we have:
for $k=1$, the left inequality is violated and the right inequality holds.
for $k=n$, the left inequality  holds and the right inequality is  violated.
Since the expression in the middle is monotonically increasing in $k$, by the mean value theorem, this means that there exists some $k_{\mathrm{left}}$ such that the left inequality holds for $1 \le k_{\mathrm{left}} < k \le n $ and some  $k_{\mathrm{right}}$ such that the right inequality holds for $1 < k < k_{\mathrm{right}} \le n $. This shows the dilemma: We have to have  $k_{\mathrm{left}} < k_{\mathrm{right}}$ for both inequalities to hold, but the mean value theorem does not give information on that.
